# How to reset iOS Push Notifications Badge number in Parse?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, push-notification, xcode6

I am using Parse iOS SDK. I have problem in resetting the badge count. I am using the tutorial(parse) code to send push notifications. I am using increment for badge, but the badge count keeps on incrementing. I am resetting the badge count in applicationDidBecomeActive: method like this,

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application { 

    PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];

    if (currentInstallation.badge != 0) {
        currentInstallation.badge = 0;
        [currentInstallation saveEventually];
    }

// ...
}
```

It just resets the badge number locally. But when I send the push notification next time, it just increments the previous count value and displays it. I guess the badge number in Parse server is not getting reset. Also, I tried to use `[currentInstallation saveInBackground];` , but it not working too. Help

Comment: That code looks correct. I use the same. Perhaps change the saveEventually to a saveInBackgroundWithBlock so that you can see any errors.

Comment: Another thought, you might be putting the app into background too quickly for the save to complete before the next push. SaveEventually is not always instant.

Comment: I tried to use saveInBackgroundWithBlock, but that method not helped me.. No errors. And server not saved value of badge.

Comment: Double check your Parse App id and client key. Make sure you're looking in the correct Parse app online. Your code looks correct, must be configuration or network issue.

Comment: Parse App id and client key is ok...

Comment: One more troubleshooting idea...create a new Parse.com app, switch the IDs in your build and see if its working on the new app.

Comment: Thanks for feedback, man) I updated Parse SDK from 1.6.2 to 1.6.3. Now, it's work fine with use method "saveInBackgroundWithBlock" as you said early.

Answer (score 3):

Try leaving away the if-statement (if you don't mind unnecessary api requests):

```
PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
currentInstallation.badge = 0;
[currentInstallation saveEventually];
```

It seems that sometimes the `installation.badge != 0` check fails.

This is how I solved my desynced badges.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. The local value of currentInstallation.badge isn't the same that the online one... Parse appears to have some issues here.